# Divs with an <a> tag only clickable when the screen is wider than 992px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For a school deliverable I need to make a horizontal bar graph with a description for each bar. This is the first HTML/CSS thing I'm making after completing the codecadamy courses. I've been able to figure out everything so far by looking at stuff on codepen, w3schools, stackoverflow, etc. But this last part is kicking my ass and I can't figure it out.

I have two lay-outs:

- the graph and description next to each other for screens wider than 1240px,
- the graph and description under each other for narrower screens

I did this by making two columns in Bootstrap and giving the container two fixed sizes. This works great on screens wider than 992 pixels, but on screens smaller than this the links don't work anymore. Some detective work with the Chrome Developer Tools shows that this coincides with a float:left that's enabled by @media (min-width:992px) in the bootstrap.css. Disabling the float on wider screens breaks the links again, but enabling it narrow screens doesn't fix them, so I'm not sure how that relates.

Here's the page: http://tijmen.kervers.nl/B1.2/competencies.html

And I think these are the questions I need to ask:

Why do the links only work when float:left is enabled?

If I failed to provide necessary information please let me know, thanks in advance!

Comment: *Bootstrap and giving the container two fixed sizes* black milk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a clearfix on your first `#bars` with Bootstrap's class `clearfix`, and it's clickable again.

---

To understand this :

Without clearfix, your block `#bars` has no height, and the second `.col-md-6` overlaps it. The links are thus unclickable :
[image: Without clearfix]

With clearfix, your block `#bars` clears the float of the second col, and has its height defined by its content. Thus, its content is brought back to front, and clickable :
[image: With clearfix]

Comment: I'm using [Brackets](brackets.io) with live preview and when I added the class to it initially worked but after reloading the page it didn't anymore. It did make me look into some other things and I somehow solved it along the way. I should look into versioning because I have no clue what fixed it.

Thanks!